# bootstrap xs grid misalign on IE and edge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Code:

```
<div style="width:310px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
             <input class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-xs-1">
        ~
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A very simple row that uses all 12 columns. This row has no problem for view above small screen but it misaligns under extra small (xs).

[image]

This bug is reproducible under latest IE (tested on Win 7 and 10) and Edge

I wonder what is causing it and is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this code example is accurate? Only say that because code says `Text` but output says `test`, so just curious if anything else differs.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII sorry...I hand typed the string again when I am formatting, but the example is accurate. I even tried to remove the string completely and nothing changed

Comment: how small is that?  I don't find this problem on Windows 10 default edge and mobile edge.

Comment: @AchmadJP minimum window size (under 325px)

Comment: ow wait, on mine the tilde is converted to the standard `-` so the error is not occurring.

Comment: this behavior happens in chrome also and will happen in all browsers because when the screen size is very small the content just does not fit horizontally and will wrap down..so you need to add media queries and reduce the size of the content also accordingly

Comment: @DhavalChheda that's exactly what bootstrap is for isn't it?

Comment: bootstraphas its set of breakpoints but when you want somethings to appear in a particular way then you need to have media queries..bootstrap  provides some automation but for precise work you might need media queries..e.g:- if i have a 4 col box and i put min -width as 50px.bootstrap cannot break that rule so it will try to adjust as muich as it can but when it cannot it will break that col to the next line..it is common to find media queries for codes written in bootstrap..

Comment: @DhavalChheda I don't get why the behavior is expected. the input doesn't have a min width but rather based on the percentage of parent's width and the "~" is definitely less than 27px. So I would expect the row to fit in the screen

Comment: margins and padding?

Comment: @DhavalChheda you are right. The padding adds up to 30px > 27px which is the width of 1 column